# Child actor does not get restarted on failure

Tags: c#, .net, akka, console-application, akka.net

I have a parent actor which is:

```
public sealed class PersistenceSupervisor : ReceiveActor
{

    protected override void PreStart()
    {
        base.PreStart();

        Become(Active);
    }

    protected override SupervisorStrategy SupervisorStrategy()
    {
        return new OneForOneStrategy(
            10,
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0),
            x =>
            {
                return Directive.Restart;
            });
    }

    private void Active(object message)
    {
        IInventorPersister inventorPersistor = new InventorPersister();
        IActorRef persister = Context.ActorOf(Props.Create<Persister>(inventorPersistor), "persisterActor");
        var task = persister.Ask(message);
        task.Wait();
        Sender.Tell(task.Result);
    }
}
```

And the child actor, that has a random fail function for test purpose:

```
public sealed class Persister : ReceiveActor
{
    private readonly IInventorPersister inventorPersister;

    protected override void PreStart()
    {
        base.PreStart();

        Become(ActiveAsync);
    }

    private async void ActiveAsync(object message)
    {
        try
        {
            var savedSender = Context.Sender;
            Task persisting = Persist(message as CreatePublication);
            await persisting;
            savedSender.Tell("Success");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    public Persister(IInventorPersister inventorPersister)        
    {
        this.inventorPersister = inventorPersister;
    }

    private async Task Persist(CreatePublication message)
    {
        RandomFailure.Fail();    
        // This function is to make an UPDATE query to db        
        await inventorPersister.Persist(message.PublicationNumber, message.Inventors);            
    }

    // Random failure for testing purpose
    private static class RandomFailure
    {
        private static readonly Random R = new Random();
        public static void Fail()
        {
            if (R.Next(0, 2) == 0)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Random failure");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is to restart the child actor until it succeeds. However, when the failure happens, the application stops right there and crash. I appreciate any help. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Some more general tips:

1. You're using `ReceiveActor` which expects to have message handlers supplied via `Receive`/`ReceiveAsync` methods inside actor's constructor. `Become(ActiveAsync)` is used by untyped actors not ReceiveActor inheritors.
2. You're active async method doesn't return a task just plain void - it's hard to predict how system will behave, when an exception will be thrown from such method.
3. Don't use `Become` inside actor's constructor or `PreStart` method if you don't have to. Exceptions thrown during actor initialization will always result in actor being stopped (even it supervision strategy was to restart it).

That being said, the simplest way is just to supply your actor will `ReceiveAsync` handler.

```cs
public sealed class Persister : ReceiveActor
{
    private readonly IInventorPersister inventorPersister;

    public Persister(IInventorPersister inventorPersister)
    {
        this.inventorPersister = inventorPersister;
        ReceiveAsync<CreatePublication>(async message =>
        {
            await Persist(message);
            Context.Sender.Tell("Success");
        });
    }
    private async Task Persist(CreatePublication message) { ... }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I don't get your answer because I would like to throw an exception on purpose to test the Supervisor Strategy

Comment: I'm not sure why do you want to test it. [Default strategy](https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net/blob/dev/src/core/Akka/Actor/SupervisorStrategy.cs#L103) of actor to most exceptions is restart. You may test it, but this way you don't test your domain, but rather the framework itself. Code I've attached shows a configuration of ReceiveActor, since I suspect the way you're initializing your actors breaks their internals.

Comment: Because I would like to make sure that if any exception happens. The child actor will be restarted until it succeeds getting data from database. Also the exception does not come from the constructor but comes from the function `RandomFailure.Fail()`. I have try your code but it doesn't work (throwing exception and crash the app)

Comment: 1. There is no sense in trying to get data from database in infinite loop, other than burning your application server down.
2. Snippet I've shown still allows you to test your code for actor retries and is actual way to how one would design actor's behavior.